# mediation in 2-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, mediation

I'm conducting 2x2 between-subject experiment research. A mediator is proposed in the model. May I know what how can I analyze the model like this:

IVs (2x2) --> M --> DV

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can approach this: 1) treating your IVs as a single 4-category independent variable, or 2) treating this as moderated mediation.

For 1), you simply create 4 dummy variables representing the 4 categories formed by a cross of the independent variable factors. It will be hard to talk about the usual quantities like the "indirect effect" or "direct effect" because there is no single effect; each effect corresponds to the effect of being in one level vs. the reference level, so there is no single effect to report. You can do omnibus tests for mediation, though, by testing whether any of the indirect effects from the dummies are different from zero.

For 2), you choose one of the the factors to be the primary IV and the other factor to be the moderator. You can request that only the "a" path (from the IV to the mediator) is moderated, or you can allow all paths to be moderated. You can then get direct and indirect effects at each level of the moderator and do tests for moderated mediation.

In the end, the choice depends on what research question you want to answer, which you didn't mention in your post. Are you interested in whether mediation is present, or are you interested specifically in the indirect effect? What kind of explanation would you give if you found mediation or moderation?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm interested in whether mediation is present as well as the indirect effect. BTW, I found an useful article by Muller et al. (2008). Adjusting for a Mediator in Models With Two Crossed Treatment Variables. Organizational Research Methods, 11(2), 224-240. doi:10.1177/1094428106296639